# Swift 4 Sort Tuples with Error

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, tuples

I have been working on Swift 3 quite a long time to be able to sort Tuples as below

```
let count = self.array1.count
let sortedTuples = (0..<count).map {(self.array2[$0], self.array3[$0], self.array1[$0], self.array4[$0], self.array5[$0], self.array6[$0], self.array7[$0], self.array8[$0])}.sorted { $0.0 > $1.0 }
self.array2 = sortedTuples.map { $0.0 }
self.array3 = sortedTuples.map { $0.1 }
self.array1 = sortedTuples.map { $0.2 }
self.array4 = sortedTuples.map { $0.3 }
self.array5 = sortedTuples.map { $0.4 }
self.array6 = sortedTuples.map { $0.5 }
self.array7 = sortedTuples.map { $0.6 }
self.array8 = sortedTuples.map { $0.7 }
```

Noting that all arrays are `String`, except `array7` is `UIColor`.

Now when migrating to Swift 4, I'm getting below error;

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

How can I break this long code to more lines to satisfy Xcode 9?

Comment: It might help to specify the type of `sortedTuples` instead of letting type inference figure that out for you.

Comment: Why do you have 8 parallel arrays? That's a big code smell; consider having *one* array of structs with 8 properties each instead.

Comment: @Hamish it's not possible through the huge code, I would like to do so

Comment: @Palle I tried with no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried to specify the input and return type of the closure? in the first map statement?

Comment: @Palle I didn't get that. Could you clarify with a simpler example?

Comment: `(0..<count).map { index -> (String, String, String, String, String, String, UIColor, String) in ...}`

Comment: @Palle the answer by vacawama is working fine. Thank you Palle for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort `array2` and keep the other arrays paired the same way.  Instead of creating a *monster* tuple, you could just sort `array2` paired with its indices (that is what `enumerated()` does) and then use the sorted indices to remap the other arrays:

```
let sortedTuples = array2.enumerated().sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
let indices = sortedTuples.map { $0.0 }
self.array2 = indices.map { array2[$0] }
self.array3 = indices.map { array3[$0] }
self.array1 = indices.map { array1[$0] }
self.array4 = indices.map { array4[$0] }
self.array5 = indices.map { array5[$0] }
self.array6 = indices.map { array6[$0] }
self.array7 = indices.map { array7[$0] }
self.array8 = indices.map { array8[$0] }
```

Comment: This is an approach I didn't think about it :) and YES, it's working more than fine. Thanks vacawama. BTW I liked your description of my tuple :) :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :)